# Why did the guards at the prison camp on Carraya IV carry weapons?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, klingon, romulan

In the begining of "[Birthright. Part II](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Birthright,_Part_II_(episode))" episode (Star Trek Next Generation 6x17) we see a camp on Carraya IV, where

> Klingons captured during [Khitomer Massacre](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Khitomer_Massacre) are living together with Romulans. Their previous guards have developed to become part of their families, having marriages between Romulans and Klingons, kids etc. They're no longer guards. On the other hand, Carraya IV is a remote planet, forgotten by Klingons, Romulans and "rest of the universe".

If that's so, why guards are carrying weapons? Against who they need to defend themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explicitly covered in the original [show script](http://leethomson.myzen.co.uk/Star_Trek/2_The_Next_Generation/Star_Trek_-_The_Next_Generation_Season_6/Star_Trek_-_The_Next_Generation_243_-_Birthright_Part_II.txt). **The guards don't usually guard anything. They've obviously taken the weapons out of a locker somewhere for the purpose of guarding Worf.**

> **Scene 4 : ANGLE - WORF**
>
> *He is sitting alone on a BENCH to one side of the compound, surveying
> it. He looks around at the activity in the compound -- a young man is
> gardening; a group of young people run and play a game; three men play
> a game with dice.*
>
> *People go about their business, occasionally casting surreptitious
> glances at the stranger in their midst. Every time Worf's eye meets
> someone else's, they seem to turn away and return to what they were
> doing.*
>
> *This place is more a village than a prison -- flowers are planted near
> the well tended barracks; the wall that once served to pen prisoners
> is still there, but the gate is left open and people come and go at
> will.*
>
> *While there are several generations of Klingons in the camp, the only
> Romulans are the middle-aged guards who have been at this post for the
> last twenty years. **Worf is the first person they've had to guard in a
> long time and they have to remind themselves to keep an eye on him and
> not be distracted by the goings on in the camp.***

Comment: Facts in scripts that never made it on screen are about as canon as novels.

Comment: @Tritium21 - The rule of thumb with trek canon is that the scripts are considered fully canonical, **unless contradicted by the episode itself**

Comment: @Tritium21 - Also, in this case the script notes are intended to show direction rather than dialogue. It seems highly unlikely that the Director would have simply ignored these.

Comment: This is a fair point

Answer (score 1):

Worf, obviously.

We only see these guards after a non-indoctrinated Klingon's presence is known  in the camp - Worf.  Worf is a [dangerous, effective warrior](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nXrlhN9rPoc); this warrants the guards taking their weapons out of storage.

Comment: Although the script supports this guess, you haven't backed up with any evidence.

Comment: Yeah, if they hadn't had weapons to deter Worf from attacking unarmed, he might have hurt himself.  They had weapons for his protection.